# Select - a few questions

Tags: c++, winsock

I have a few questions about select function, i wrote this code:

```
void TCPSerwer::sel()
{
    struct timeval tv = {1, 0};
    fd_set temp_list = m_RecvList;
    //if(select(m_fdmax + 1, &temp_list, NULL, NULL, &tv) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    if(select(0, &temp_list, NULL, NULL, &tv) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        perror( "select" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= m_fdmax; i++ )
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(i, &temp_list))
        {
            // New connection
            if(i == m_ListenSocket)
            {
                acceptClient();
            }

            // Data from client
            else
            {
                PacketHeader header;
                int nbytes = recv(i, (char*)(&header), sizeof(PacketHeader),

                // Error
                if(nbytes < 0)
                {
                    disconnectClient(i);
                }
                // success
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "type: " << header.type << "   len: " << header.length << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can give first arg to select function and i can don't do that, but why ? Why a should give first arg to select ? m_fdmax is highest number of socket, but this code working without this arg.

Next question is, why select need timeout ? When i don't give this arg select marks all socket as socket that can be readable but select doing this when socket haven't any data to read. When i give this arg i don't have this problem. But why ?

if m_fdmax is highest number of socket, i have to find next highest number of socket when i close connection, Right ? And i should doing this that:

```
int size = m_ClientVector.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   if(m_ClientVector[i] > m_fdmax)
           m_fdmax = m_ClientVector[i];
}
```

Comment: Windows' implementation of `select()` ignores the first parameter. This is stated as much in the [`select()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> I can give first arg to select function and i can don't do that, but why ? Why a should give first arg to select ? m_fdmax is highest number of socket, but this code working without this arg.

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx).  The `select()` function on Windows ignores the first parameter, so it does not matter what you pass to it.

> Next question is, why select need timeout ?

It does not **NEED** a timeout, but you can **OPTIONALLY** provide a timeout if desired.  This way, if the requested socket state is not reached before the timeout elapses, `select()` can still exit and not deadlock the calling thread indefinitely, allowing it to do other things.

> When i don't give this arg select marks all socket as socket that can be readable but select doing this when socket haven't any data to read.

If you do not provide a timeout, `select()` waits indefinitely until the requested socket state actually occurs.  A socket can be marked as readable if it has data to read, but it can also be marked as readible if it has been `gracefully` disconnected by the other party.  A subsequent call to `recv()` will tell you which is the case (`recv()` returns -1 on error, 0 on disconnect, an >0 on data).  Again, [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx).

> if m_fdmax is highest number of socket, i have to find next highest number of socket when i close connection, Right ?

If you want to calculate the highest socket number (which Windows does not care about, but other platforms do), then you would have to re-calculate the highest socket number every time you call `select()`, or at least whenever you re-prepare the `fd_set` structure (which you need to do every time you call `select()` anyway).

> And i should doing this that

On Windows, no.  On other platforms, yes.

With that said, try this code on Windows instead:

```
void TCPSerwer::sel()
{
    struct timeval tv = {1, 0};
    fd_set temp_list = m_RecvList;

    int ret = select(0, &temp_list, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        perror( "select" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    if (ret == 0) // timeout
        return;

    for(u_int i = 0; i < temp_list.fd_count; ++i)
    {
        SOCKET s = temp_list.fd_array[i];

        // New connection
        if (s == m_ListenSocket)
        {
            acceptClient();
            continue;
        }

        // Data from client

        PacketHeader header;

        char *pheader = (char*) &header;
        int nbytes = 0;

        do
        {
            ret = recv(s, pheader, sizeof(PacketHeader)-nbytes, 0);   

            // success
            if (ret > 0)
                nbytes += ret;
        }
        while ((ret > 0) && (nbytes < sizeof(PacktHeader)));

        // Error or disconnect
        if (nbytes < sizeof(PacktHeader))
        {
            disconnectClient(i);
            continue;
        }

        // success
        std::cout << "type: " << header.type << "   len: " << header.length << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*About the timeout:*
`select` can use a `struct timeval` to timeout. If you pass a `NULL` pointer, `select` will wait until an event comes. If you pass an address to a `struct timeval`, `select` will return even if there's not event (in your code, `select` will return every second).

*About the fdmax:* Yes you have to find the highest socket, and your snippet is correct.

*Other:* You don't have any `FD_SET` in your code. Usually, the sockets are setted (via `FD_SET` so) in the loop which find the highest socket.
**EDIT:**  My bad I didn't seen the `fd_set temp_list = m_RecvList;` in your code. We will need more code in order to analyze your problem with `select`.

Comment: The OP's code is running on Windows, as evident by the fact that Winsock is being asked about.  Windows does not use the first parameter of `select()`, thus it is commonly set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, I want use this code on Windows and Linux, and now I doing that:
When I have a new connection:

```
bool TCPSerwer::acceptClient()
{
SOCKET new_client = accept(m_ListenSocket, 0, 0);

if(new_client == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return false;

m_ClientVector.push_back(new_client);

    // Add to FD
    FD_SET(new_client, &m_RecvList);

if(new_client > m_fdmax)
    m_fdmax = new_client;

return true;
}
```

When i want to close connection:

```
void TCPSerwer::disconnectClient(const SOCKET& client)
{
int size = m_ClientVector.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if(m_ClientVector[i] == client)
    {
        closesocket(m_ClientVector[i]);

        // Delete from FD
        FD_CLR(m_ClientVector[i], &m_RecvList);

        m_ClientVector.erase(m_ClientVector.begin() + i);

        break;
    }
}

// re-calculateing the highest socket number
size = m_ClientVector.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if(m_ClientVector[i] > m_fdmax)
        m_fdmax = m_ClientVector[i];
}
```

}

I havr one question to you **Remy Lebeau**, your recv function look that:

```
recv(s, pheader, sizeof(PacketHeader)-nbytes, 0);
```

but recv save data at the being of bufor ? Meybe this should look that:

```
recv(s, pheader + nbytes, sizeof(PacketHeader)-nbytes, 0);
```